# Same size of the last items with Flex Layout in the grid system

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have a problem using the flex layout grid system.

Let's say I have a grid of 6 items and I want 4 items per rows. So I would do like this :

```
<div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1px">
<div fxFlex="calc(25% - 1px)" fxLayoutAlign="center end" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span fxFlex>{{ item }}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is that the last two items on the second row have a different size than the items on the first row. They would have a size of 50% of the full size row but the item of the first row would be 25% of the full size row.

So how would I do to have all items with 25% of the full size row on two rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is using `fxFlex="25"` instead of `fxFlex="calc(25% - 1px)"` and removing `fxLayoutGap` and solve this by adding `padding: 1px` for example.

I have create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-rtqkj6) to show this possible solution (width padding: 3px):

```
<div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row wrap">
    <div fxFlex="25" fxLayoutAlign="center end" *ngFor="let item of items" style="padding: 3px;">
        <span fxFlex>{{ item }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do not want to remove `fxLayoutGap` use `fxFlex="24"` instead.

```
<div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1px">
    <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <span fxFlex>{{ item }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both answers are great. I can't really make exactly what I wanted to do (the 1px gap not a padding) but the solution is very close. Thanks a lot. I would check the fastest answer.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, but a hack. The spacing will never really work like this :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is a combination of the `fxLayoutGap="1px"` in the parent flex container as well as the `fxFlex="calc(25% - 1px)"` in your flex children.

If you simply remove the `fxLayoutGap="1px"` and change your children to `fxFlex="25"` you will get the desired behavior. **However, that will result in your gap being removed.**

**If you really want to keep you gap than I suggest you be consistent and use a percent like the following example:** [Here is the working stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-czyzqk)

```
<div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap=".2%">
      <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
        <span style="background-color: green" fxFlex>1</span>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
        <span style="background-color: yellow" fxFlex>2</span>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
        <span style="background-color: blue" fxFlex>3</span>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
        <span style="background-color: orange" fxFlex>4</span>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
        <span style="background-color: pink" fxFlex>5</span>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="24" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
        <span style="background-color: red" fxFlex>6</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thks for reply I understand the problem with the uncompatibility of fxLayoutGap and fxFlex

Comment: Sure - no problem.